# How can I debug only my code in android studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

[image]I have been facing a problem in android studio. Whenever I debug my code it takes me to the libraries methods that are associated to the break point. According to the documentation F8 key is used for STEP OVER but it did not work in my case. I tried to add filter in Preferences->debugging->stepping with com.android.* or android.* but non of them are working. I can not add all the import libs one by one in the filter. I am using android 1.0.+ version. Please suggest how can I overcome this problem.

Edit:-

It will take me through all the grey methods (shown in the pics) on F8 key that are system Libs. I don't want to go through these methods.

Many Thanks

Comment: I think its step into.  f7

Comment: No F7 is for Step INTO.

Comment: Try adding more break points and when that happens just "Step over", I this that's F9. That way you'll jump to the next break point instead of downing in the source code.

Comment: Thanks, f9 is  use to jump on next break point.what if I want to debug a block of code that start from break point that I put on before the next break point without entering in the libs?